# "A fatal error has occured: Couldn't create admin" error when installing Ubuntu OpenStack - Canonical Distribution

Tags: server, cloud, openstack, canonical, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to install the new Canonical Distribution on a virtual environment following the guide published here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

but during the installation the installer gave me this error:
"
A fatal error has occured: Couldn't create admin
See /home/user/.cloud-install/command.log
"
In the file I saw this lines:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9006273/

someone knows what went wrong and which is the solution?

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that Installing MaaS from a fresh Ubuntu Server 14.04lts ISO, then I've upgraded it via ppa repositories as reported on [guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack), then I continue to follow the guide but I've reported other new errors signed in this new "Ask Question"

[how to install Ubuntu Openstack - Canonical Distribution on a virtual environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552383/how-to-install-ubuntu-openstack-canonical-distribution-on-a-virtual-environmen)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is

```
Database.connect(**conn_params)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect\n    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=asyn
c)\ndjango.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\ncould not connect to serve
r: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\n\n'}
```

It looks like there is something happening during the MAAS installation. Can you verify MAAS did get installed?

Comment: No, because it didn't finish to install MaaS, it stopped during the installation, this is the screenshot of this error: http://pbrd.co/1uaW2zR