# installing Ubuntu Openstack - Canonical Distribution on a virtual environment

Tags: juju, maas, postgresql, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I've tried to install **Ubuntu Openstack - Canonical Distribution** using [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) new Ubuntu guide.

During step 3, i use the following command to install MaaS;

```
sudo apt install maas
```

I've received this error:

[image: apt-get install maas error]

There is also an error when I try to install the maas-region-controller:

[image: maas-region-controller error]

This means that the error is related to PostgreSQL.

Has anyone reported the same error, and how does one resolve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please make your comment an answer and mark it answered. After that make a new post with your problem.

Comment: I made an answer for you, just click the gray "check" button bellow the vote buttons to mark it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***From OP's second comment;***

I resolved the problem with re-installing MaaS via the Ubuntu ISO, without using the CLI.